# Django Template Language: Using a for loop with else

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In the Django template language is there away to use the the else clause with a for loop? I relies I can use an if check before the for loop but that gets repetitive.

python for-else

```
list = []

for i in list:
    print i
else:
    print 'list is empty'
```

Django template for-else (my guess)

```
<h1>{{ game.title}}</h1>

<table>
    <tr> 

{% for platform in game.platform_set.all %}       
    <td>{{ platform.system }} -- ${{ platform.price}}</td> 
{% else %}
    <td>No Platforms</td>
{% endfor %}

    </tr>
</table>

<a href="{% url 'video_games:profile' game.id %}"></a>
```

Comment: mipadi's answer is right to the question "find if a list of item is empty", but  OP is using `for..else` wrongly.

Django Template `for..empty` - `empty` means that the for-loop does not have any item.

while

Python `for..else` - `else` means that the for-loop did not exit (break).

Comment: Also, you should not name a list "list"! After the line `list = []` you will not be able to call `list()`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`for...empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty), which is basically the Django equivalent (replaces the `else` keyword with `empty`).

Comment: As Andrew said (in a comment on the question), `for..empty` is what the OP is asking for, but `for..else` does something **completely** different in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old post. Adding an answer for future reference. There is no explicit way to achieve `for..else` but we can do something like the following.

```
{% for x in some_list %}
    ... awesome html and more here
    
    {% if forloop.last %}
        ... executes only if this is the last time through the loop
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps. More reading [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)